# How to connect/pair devices correctly on wifi direct?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, wifi-direct

It is my first program on wifi direct so I made a simple program that just discover all nearby devices and then try to connect to one of them the discovery works fine and gets all the devices the problem is in the connection that always fails after using this function `WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync()` it keeps paring for too long and then it fails always.
I was following the code on this microsoft tutorial: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-98

Here is my code:

```
// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App7
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        DeviceInformationCollection DevicesFound;
        WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher pub;
        WiFiDirectConnectionListener listener;
        CancellationTokenSource m_CancellationTokenSource;
        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String DeviceSelector = WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector(WiFiDirectDeviceSelectorType.AssociationEndpoint);
            DevicesFound = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceSelector);
            if(DevicesFound.Count>0)
            {
                connectedDeviceslist.ItemsSource = DevicesFound;
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(DevicesFound[0].Name);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = connectedDeviceslist.SelectedIndex;
            String deviceID = DevicesFound[selectedIndex].Id;
            var selecetedDevice = DevicesFound[selectedIndex];
            try
            {
                WiFiDirectConnectionParameters connectionParams = new WiFiDirectConnectionParameters();
                connectionParams.GroupOwnerIntent = Convert.ToInt16("1");
                connectionParams.PreferredPairingProcedure = WiFiDirectPairingProcedure.GroupOwnerNegotiation;

                m_CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(selecetedDevice.Id, connectionParams).AsTask(m_CancellationTokenSource.Token);
                var EndpointPairs = wfdDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async() =>
                {
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                });
            }




        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pub = new WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher();
            pub.Advertisement.ListenStateDiscoverability = WiFiDirectAdvertisementListenStateDiscoverability.Normal;
            listener = new WiFiDirectConnectionListener();
            listener.ConnectionRequested += OnConnectionRequested;
            pub.Start();
        }
        private async void OnConnectionRequested(WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender, WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                var ConnectionRequest = args.GetConnectionRequest();

                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                var dialogTask = tcs.Task;
                var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Connection request received from " + ConnectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Name, "Connection Request");

                // Add commands and set their callbacks; both buttons use the same callback function instead of inline event handlers 
                messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Accept", null, 0));
                messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Decline", null, 1));

                // Set the command that will be invoked by default 
                messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;

                // Set the command to be invoked when escape is pressed 
                messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                {
                    // Show the message dialog 
                    var commandChosen = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

                    tcs.SetResult((commandChosen.Label == "Accept") ? true : false);
                });

                var fProceed = await dialogTask;

                if (fProceed == true)
                {
                    var tcsWiFiDirectDevice = new TaskCompletionSource<WiFiDirectDevice>();
                    var wfdDeviceTask = tcsWiFiDirectDevice.Task;

                   // WriteToOutput("Connecting to " + ConnectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Name + "...");

                    WiFiDirectConnectionParameters ConnectionParams = new WiFiDirectConnectionParameters();

                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ConnectionParams.GroupOwnerIntent = 14;
                            tcsWiFiDirectDevice.SetResult(await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(ConnectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Id, ConnectionParams));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           // WriteToOutput("FromIdAsync task threw an exception: " + ex.ToString());
                        }
                    });

                    WiFiDirectDevice wfdDevice = await wfdDeviceTask;

                    var EndpointPairs = wfdDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();

                   /* m_ConnectedDevices.Add("dummy", wfdDevice);

                    WriteToOutput("Devices connected on L2, listening on IP Address: " + EndpointPairs[0].LocalHostName.ToString() + " Port: " + Globals.strServerPort);

                    StreamSocketListener listenerSocket = new StreamSocketListener();
                    listenerSocket.ConnectionReceived += OnSocketConnectionReceived;

                    await listenerSocket.BindEndpointAsync(EndpointPairs[0].LocalHostName, Globals.strServerPort);*/
                }
                else
                {
                  /*  // Decline the connection request
                    WriteToOutput("Connection request from " + ConnectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Name + " was declined");

                    ConnectionRequest.Dispose();*/
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //WriteToOutput("FromIdAsync threw an exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: The error is useless. It's an `AggregateException` because you use async programming. Look at the `InnerExpections` for the actual cause of the problem. Tell us what it is and where in your code it happens, also try to reduce the size of the sample code to the minimum replrodusable.

Comment: @EliAlgranti check it now please

Comment: I've edited my comment. You need to look at the `InnerExceptions` collection for the actual error.

Comment: @EliAlgranti this is what i get Unhandled exception at 0x76465A81 (combase.dll) in App7.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x0588F218, 0x00000001).